Garage door opener motor goes down, not up
I have a Craftsman garage door opener with 0.5 HP. When I hit my remote button or my wall button, the only response I have from the motor is it goes down. It will not go up though.

This usually happens when the springs are not adjusted to give enough assist to open the door..

Pursuant to the comment of @RMDman, consider to release the locking handle, returning your door to manual operation. If you find it difficult to lift the door, your springs are not properly adjusted. Use caution and do not lift the door too high if it seems heavy. When the release handle is pulled, the door may hop open a foot or so. This would be a good sign and allow you to focus on the motor and drive unit.

Jumping up is not a good sign, @fred_dot_u - the door should stay where it's at at any point in the travel where you stop it and let go of it, if properly adjusted.

Lubrication of the roller shafts might solve this. Best to use a product labelled garage door lubricant, but in a pinch you could use oil or light grease. Don't use WD-40 because it is not a lubricant. If you have used it, then it would evaporate without leaving any lubricant film so deliver the correct lubricant to the same place.

I thought the indication that a door was properly "balanced" was that it would stay in place near the "middle" position of travel so say 4 ft off the ground, rather than any position. Of course this presumes that the door is appropriately friction free. A relative recently called me to find out why her fairly new German made Sommer opener would not open the door. This opener does not require lubrication of the fixed chain. I found the door had a lot of frictional resistance and that lubing the roller shafts with  "garage door lube" (3-in1 brand) in an aerosol can restored function.

I have a Craftsman opener with a screw drive. When disconnected from the opener my door will stay in place at about 5 ft above the ground but will fall if below that. You could disconnect the  door at the trolly by pulling the release cord and see if the opener activates the up motion to move the trolly toward the motor. If it does move, then suspect the door is too hard to move and needs lube or spring tensioning. If it doesn't move then suspect the micro-switch above the door or something electronic in the motor unit. Does the door reverse on the way down if the beam is interrupted?
